# Was my PS4 hacked or my account stolen?

Tags: ps4

My PS4 is at home, I have no way of getting into contact with it. I'm not sure if my PS4 was hacked or if someone took over my account. Someone bought about $200 worth of stuff from my account and I don't know if it was a hack or not. Nobody has my login and even if someone did try to log in, won't I see it if someone is trying to access it if I have the 2-step verification thing? I'm not sure what to do, I already filed a police report just in case, once I get back into the building. Someone help!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! It does seem like your account may have been hacked in some manner. However, we are not Sony support and you will much better help contacting them

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for Sony support, not the Arqade community.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, there are several tutorials on what to do if your Playstation account is compromised.

From [PS4Home](https://www.ps4home.com/ps4-account-hacked-heres-what-to-do/):

- [Change your Playstation network password immediately](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/How-to-Reset-Your-PSN-Account-Password?language=en_US)
- [Enable Two-factor authentication](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/PS4-2-Step-Verification?language=en_US)
- Contact your bank to reverse current charges and prevent future charges from Sony
- If possible, use the [PS4's remote play function](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/ps4/remote-play/) (requires app download) to the hacker's console and deactivate it as the primary user
- Alternatively, [contact Sony customer support](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/corporate/contactus/) to have them rescind the the hacker's status as the primary user of your account for you
- File a police report on the incident